# What is the difference between dynamic typing, duck typing, and parametric polymorphism?

Tags: ruby, language-agnostic

What is the difference between dynamic typing, duck typing, polymorphism, and parametric polymorphism?

I ask because Ruby has each of these ([according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)), though I am interested more generally.

Comment: Who says Ruby uses parametric polymorphism?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)

Answer (score 2):

**Dynamic typing** means you don't need to define the type of a variable, the language interpreter  will try to guess the type of that variable (number, boolean, string etc).

**Duck typing** means that we are not interested in what type an object is, instead we are more concerned in the functional aspect of the object: if an object returns those methods we are interested in, then this means that the object satisfy our requirements. Hence the well known phrase: *"if a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, that bird is a duck"*.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism):  **parametric polymorphism** is a way to make a language more expressive, while still maintaining full static type-safety. Using parametric polymorphism, a function or a data type can be written generically so that it can handle values identically without depending on their type.

Comment: I don't think your definition of dynamic typing is correct - ML uses static typing, but you don't have to tell it what types variables are, they are instead inferred.

Comment: None of those are correct. 1. Dynamic typing means that type checking is done dynamically. What you are talking about is implicit typing. And there most certainly is no guessing going on. 2. Of course, we are interested in what type an object is, that's what typing is all about. Duck typing means that the type is based on the behavioral specification of an object (its protocol in Ruby terms or its interface in Java terms) and not its class. 3. While that definition is correct, you are missing the most important point: it doesn't make sense in Ruby, PP is a feature of static typing.